# AWS Beanstalk missing sdk.class.php

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I deployed a very simple php webpage into an AWS ElasticBeanstalk instance. The file fails right after

```
<?php
require_once('sdk.class.php');
// more code...
```

I can see from /var/log/httpd/application-error_log that sdk.class.php is missing:

```
[Wed Jun 13 03:30:15 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Stack trace:
[Wed Jun 13 03:30:15 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP   1. {main}() /var/www/html/index.php:0
[Wed Jun 13 03:30:45 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Warning:  require_once(sdk.class.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/index.php on line 9
[Wed Jun 13 03:30:45 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Stack trace:
[Wed Jun 13 03:30:45 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP   1. {main}() /var/www/html/index.php:0
[Wed Jun 13 03:30:45 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required 'sdk.class.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/html/index.php on line 9
```

Shouldn't sdk.class.php be included by default to every ElasticBeanstalk instance? Or am I missing something? The code works fine on my notebook where I have sdk.class.php properly installed and configured.

thanks

Answer (score 2):

The problem with this solution seems to be that when autoscaling starts new instances it won't be installed on these machines.

Better to download it into your projects folder (in order to push it with the next release) and use it from there.

- git clone git://github.com/amazonwebservices/aws-sdk-for-php.git AWSSDKforPHP
- OR download from http://aws.amazon.com/de/sdkforphp/

Answer (score 0):

I ended up getting the answer myself.

The AWS PHP SDK does not come installed by default on the ElasticBeanstalk instance (which I think it should!). I had to install myself first logging into the instance (by ssh keypair) and becoming root

```
sudo su
```

then I used the info here http://pear.amazonwebservices.com/ to install the SDK

```
pear install aws/sdk
pear upgrade aws/sdk
```

Then I copied the config sample and updated with my AWS key and secret key

```
cp /usr/share/pear/AWSSDKforPHP/config-sample.inc.php /usr/share/pear/AWSSDKforPHP/config.inc.php
```

And I also had to change my PHP code from

```
require_once('sdk.class.php');
```

to

```
require_once 'AWSSDKforPHP/sdk.class.php';
```

refreshed the web page and it worked!

Comment: If you're satisfied with your answer to your question then please mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: This will fail suddenly when your instance is replaced. n0mad's answer is the way to go.